# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.isAsyncStarted

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I've been trying to run a simple Dynamic Web Project and getting a HTTP 500 Internal Server Error and I'm not sure how to read the output to understand what I need to do to remedy the situation.

Console's output on running the project (identical when running index.htm):

> Starting preview server on port 8080
>
> Modules:   HelloWorld (/HelloWorld)
>
> 2016-04-25 20:36:05.796:INFO::main: Logging initialized @299ms
>   2016-04-25 20:36:05.897:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.13.v20150730
>   2016-04-25 20:36:06.045:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO
>   JSP Support for /HelloWorld, did not find
>   org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet 2016-04-25
>   20:36:06.070:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started
>   o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@2c8d66b2{/HelloWorld,file:/C:/Users/Joseph/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/HelloWorld/,AVAILABLE}{C:/Users/Joseph/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/HelloWorld}
>   2016-04-25 20:36:06.131:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started
>   ServerConnector@531be3c5{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080} 2016-04-25
>   20:36:06.132:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @638ms 2016-04-25
>   20:36:08.154:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:qtp1225358173-14: Error for
>   /HelloWorld/ java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.isAsyncStarted()Z   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:684)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:595)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:191)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:72)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:588)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 2016-04-25
>   20:36:08.156:WARN:oejs.HttpChannel:qtp1225358173-14: /HelloWorld/
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.isAsyncStarted()Z   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:684)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 2016-04-25
>   20:41:36.005:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:qtp1225358173-20: Error for
>   /HelloWorld/ java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.isAsyncStarted()Z   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:684)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:595)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:191)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:72)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:588)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 2016-04-25
>   20:41:36.005:WARN:oejs.HttpChannel:qtp1225358173-20: /HelloWorld/
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.isAsyncStarted()Z   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:684)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 2016-04-25
>   20:41:47.649:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:qtp1225358173-14: Error for
>   /HelloWorld/ java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.isAsyncStarted()Z   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:684)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:595)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:191)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:72)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:588)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 2016-04-25
>   20:41:47.650:WARN:oejs.HttpChannel:qtp1225358173-14: /HelloWorld/
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.isAsyncStarted()Z   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:684)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 2016-04-25
>   20:43:02.742:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:qtp1225358173-16: Error for
>   /HelloWorld/index.htm java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.isAsyncSupported()Z     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.sendData(DefaultServlet.java:926)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:534)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 2016-04-25
>   20:43:02.742:WARN:oejs.HttpChannel:qtp1225358173-16:
>   /HelloWorld/index.htm java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.isAsyncStarted()Z   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:684)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I'm using the most updated version of Eclipse and Java 1.8.0_71

code from HelloWorld.java is as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;


public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("");
        out.println("");
        out.println("Hello World!");
        out.println("");
        out.println("");

}
}
```

Code from index.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="HelloWorld">Execute</a>
</body>
</html>
```

and just to make sure I'll post the web.xml document as well

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>HelloWorld</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <description>
        </description>
        <display-name>HelloWorld</display-name>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/HelloWorld</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.isAsyncStarted() while using Mockito with Junit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23759690/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-servlet-http-httpservletrequest-isasyncstarte)

Comment: I was using Dynamic Web Module 2.4 as directed by my instructor (because we'll be doing something with SQL Databases that requires that version, I think?), and all other options are default. I tried using Dynamic Web Module 3.0 and got the same error. Is there a part I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I wasn't able to get a solution while continuing to use the most recent Mars build of Eclipse. However, I switched to the last Kepler build of Eclipse (which I found out is the build the teacher was using at the time of his recordings) and all issues have been solved.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, the first few lines of INFO:
NO JSP Support for /HelloWorld,

Since you mapped the HelloWorld Servlet with path /HelloWord
you have to create a corresponding JSP in order to fix this error.

It is possible to make use of Servlet to create Web View, but this is 
a MVC model, Servlet and JSP as controller and view. You should not be doing the view stuff inside the controller.

See if you can fix the info by removing 
/HelloWorld
in your web.xml

And the critical error part:
Error for /HelloWorld/ java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.isAsyncStarted()Z

There is no such method for isAsyncStarted, you sure you are using the correct API level? To make use of this method, you have to use version 3.0 rather than 2.4 which stated in your web.xml file.

Comment: I don't even know what a JSP is, my teacher hasn't mentioned one or made one in any of the examples he's done. He just made a dynamic web project with version 2.4, created the servlet and the html files and it ran. I've been trying to email him for a month and all I get are links back to videos I've combed over for hours. I tried with 3.0 like you said and it came back with the same error codes.

Comment: i suspect that you are using Jetty which is a more easy jsp servlet framework to use, but it also comes with different rules that may differ from your teacher, is Jetty required by the course? otherwise i would just use Java EE ecplise to start from beginning (or Spring mvc for later work)

Comment: No, Jetty is not required. I thought I was using Java EE eclipse to make this, though. I have it selected as the perspective and I've downloaded Eclipse for Java EE developers.